# Problems with saving image with OpenCV?

Tags: java, android, opencv

So, this is what I want. I have a camera frame where a circle is drawn using OpenCV. Now, I have a button which allows a user to capture an image frame and then save the image in internal storage. But then here is the problem.  I don't want the circle in the image frame to be in the saved image. How do i eliminate the circle before saving it and then once the image is saved, the circle is back on the screen?

Comment: draw the circle on a clone of the image. render the clone, save the original.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood it right.
You override `mrgba` matrix, while calling `Imgproc.circle(mrgba,new Point(centerx,centery),200,new Scalar(255,0,0),10);`. First, copy the image matrix, like you did with `black` and then draw the circle itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
#create a clone (circle) of original (mrgba)
BufferedImage circle = new BufferedImage(widthOfImage, heightOfImage, 
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g =circle.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(mrgba, 0, 0, null);

Imgproc.circle(circle,new Point(centerx,centery),200,new Scalar(255,0,0),10);  #put circle on circle

cv2.imshow("Image", circle) //show circle
cv2.imwrite(/path/to/file/name, mrgba) //save original
```

something along those lines.